# PyQt5 below Qlabel space width

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am learning PyQt5. How can I remove huge space below the Qlable:

https://hizliresim.com/Lr9ujj

This is my code:

```
class TftpTab(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        host = QLabel("Host: ")
        hostEdit = QLineEdit()


        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(host)
        layout.addWidget(hostEdit)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are better off using `QFormLayout`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class TftpTab(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        host = QLabel("Host: ")
        hostEdit = QLineEdit()

        layout = QFormLayout(self)
        layout.addRow(host, hostEdit)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TftpTab()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

---

**Update**

> But if I add another Qlabel and QLineedit in same raw how can I add ?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class TftpTab(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        host = QLabel("Host: ")
        hostEdit = QLineEdit()

        layout = QFormLayout(self)
        layout.addRow(host, hostEdit)

        layout.addRow(QLabel("Hello: "), QLineEdit("gogogo"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TftpTab()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much it good for me, but if I add another Qlabel and QLineedit in same raw how can I add ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think I cant explain how can I do HOST |(text area) | right next to  HELLO |(text area)|

Answer (score 1):

Set the vertical size policy of your label to `Fixed`.
Your problem is that the line edit has `Fixed` set but the label hasn't. So the label will grow with the parent widget (tab in your case).

See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum for the possible options.

Another viable tool to control where a window grows if you have no widgets to fill the space are spacers, which you can also add to the layout. A vertical spacer in your case that you add below the hostEdit.